# lack of icons for iPad/iPhone when loading an app on itunes connect libgdx

Tags: ios, iphone, libgdx, app-store-connect

**EDIT: SOLUTION IN THE ANSWER**

I just uploaded an application made ​​in libgdx on itunes connect , and my problem is that I get this email :

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Surf Survivor". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png
>   format for iOS versions >= 7.0.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS
>   versions >= 7.0.
>
> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS
>   versions >= 7.0.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Now , I've already added (Icon-76.png Icon-120.png Icon-152.png) to the folders of icons giving them as image name names there are in the text of the email , I reloaded the app but the error persists . how can I solve it ? how to add these images to project libgdx ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

add this:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon</string>
            <string>Icon-72</string>
            <string>Icon-76</string>  //add here
            <string>Icon-120</string> //add here
            <string>Icon-152</string> //add here
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

inside the file project\ios\info.plist.xml